# Clickable navigation with sub navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´ve got this navigation structure:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-top mod_navigation " >
    <div class="ws-navbar-collapse pull-left">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="submenu mega ncol-3 first nav-item dropdown subnav">
                <a class="" href="url" >
                    <span itemprop="name">Lösungen</span>
                </a>

                <div class="subnav-container">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <ul class="nav sub-nav level-2">
                            <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                <a class=" " href="url" >
                                    <span itemprop="name">Digitalisierung</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And I would like the click effect from this page:
https://www.invisionapp.com/

I've tried it with this js script, but its not working:

```
$('ul li.nav-item').on('click', function() {
    if(!$('.subnav-container').is(':visible')){
        $(".subnav-container" ).slideDown();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
    } else {
        $(".subnav-container" ).slideUp();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

So if the main navigation point got the class "submenu", the sub navigation "subnav-container" should slide down on click.

Comment: You seem to have specified some requirements instead of asking a question. Do you have a specific issue about this you need help with, or are you looking for people to quote you costs to complete this for you? If the latter, it would appear you've got the wrong site.

Comment: well issue is you are still clicking the `.nav-item` when you are clicking on the link inside of it. So you need to cancel the click within it, or change your event to only listen for the click on the anchor that is a direct child.

Comment: Sorry, I fergot the js script.

Comment: But .subnav-container is a child element of li.